# how to retry if cannot find element in Nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js

I want to retry if nightwatch does not click on an element. How can I do that?

I have the following code:

```
 this.browser.isVisible('.signUp', function (result) {
            if (result.value && result.length) {
                for(var i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
                    this.browser.click(this.element.login.signInBtn);
                    var check = this.browser.url(function(result) {
                        // on login page
                        console.log(result);
                        if (result.value.indexOf("#login") !== -1) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    if (check) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }.bind(this));
```

Comment: Can you explain why you would need to retry something?  Generally if you need to retry, something is not working as expected and that's what should be fixed, not the test

Answer (score 3):

-retries n will not run before and after function so this will not work as expected. You should try --suiteRetries n.

Comment: what's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

You can retry test cases with [--retries](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#command-line-options) command-line option. Example `nightwatch --retries 2` will retry failed test case two additional times.

However I will not recommend you using that. I would first explore other options to make sure that element can be clicked. Like example waiting for it to become visible with [waitForElementVisible](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#waitForElementVisible)

`this.browser.waitForElementVisible(this.element.login.signInBtn, 1000);`